# Is there any alternative to SpamAssassin?

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, spam

I'm looking for an alternative to Spamassassin. Anyone tried [rspamd](https://bitbucket.org/vstakhov/rspamd/wiki/Home) ?

Comment: As i always ask in questions like this, whats wrong with SpamAssassin ? - It'll help people make recommendations

Comment: I realize it's a few years late but search engine visitors find this still. I wrote up a comparison of running rspamd side-by-side with spamassassin in [this github issue](https://github.com/haraka/Haraka/pull/964) and some might find it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You may take a look at [ASSP](http://assp.sourceforge.net/). Works great so far.

Answer (score 3):

I can point rspamd, and it's not written in perl!

https://bitbucket.org/vstakhov/rspamd/wiki/Home

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: A quick search for rspamd should suffice if the link breaks, it's not like he provided just a link. Also see other answers.

Answer (score 2):

[**DSPAM**](http://www.nuclearelephant.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Don't overlook outsourced spam filter (Postini et al.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the Yandex Spam Defense - http://so.yandex.ru/all/index.xml
It is a highly-reliable anti-spam system, used to protect millions of Yandex (one of the most popular Russian mail-hoster) from being flooded with spam.
I like also  Symantec Brightmail Anti-Spam and Sybari Advanced Spam Manager (both can work with Domino and Exchange).

By the way, I really don't think that SpamAssassin is a bad thing to use, I think opposite, if you have enough RAM to run it you will get really nice results.

Comment: For those of us who cannot read Russian, here is some English http://help.yandex.com/mail/security/antispam.xml