# Does postfix reject spoofed senders?

Tags: email, postfix, spoofing

Is there a reliable way to reject incoming mails with a spoofed e-mail address?

What kind of checks does postfix run normally on incoming mails?

- does postfix check the reverse dns by default?
- does postfix have any other checks built-in and activated by default?
- what kind of filters / milters are useful to prevent accepting spoofed mails?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Take a look at Postfix's configuration variable [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically email was run over **Simple** Mail Transfer Protocol. It's very simple so there are no spoofing prevention mechanism in its earlier specs. Take a look on these two excellent answers about email spoofing on security.SE

- [Why is it even possible to forge sender header in e-mail?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/why-is-it-even-possible-to-forge-sender-header-in-e-mail)
- [How can PayPal spoof emails so easily to say it comes from someone else?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9487/how-can-paypal-spoof-emails-so-easily-to-say-it-comes-from-someone-else).

> Is there a reliable way to reject incoming mails with a spoofed e-mail address?

Over the years, there are some techniques implemented to identify spoofed email address, for example:

- SPF: This DNS records detail which servers are allowed to send mail for your domain. See [this canonical question for SPF](https://serverfault.com/q/369460/218590).
- Sender ID: *Fork* of SPF
- DKIM: is a method of embedding digital signatures in mail headers. It can be verified using public keys published in the DNS.
- DMARC

See also our canonical question about this topic: [Fighting Spam - What can I do as an: Email Administrator, Domain Owner, or User?](https://serverfault.com/q/419407/218590)

> What kind of checks does postfix run normally on incoming mails?

To find out what default config shipped with postfix, please run `postconf -d`. And then take a look on **smtpd_*_restriction**. As default, postfix just run two checks,

```
permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
```

- Parameter *permit_mynetworks* is [permit email which originates from your network](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#permit_mynetworks).
- Parameter *reject_unauth_destination* is basic setting to make sure that your server doesn't became open relay, visit [this page](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unauth_destination) for brief explanation.

> does postfix check the reverse dns by default?

Yes, but postfix only gave warning when reverse dns check fail. Here the sample warning from maillog.

```
Aug 22 10:37:17 mx postfix/smtpd[54487]: warning: hostname st.example.com does not resolve to address 192.168.231.235
```

If you consider to *reject* client based on their rDNS, see the discussion over here: [Is it good practice or too draconian to reject mails from mailservers with no RDNS](https://serverfault.com/q/540399/218590)

> does postfix have any other checks built-in and activated by default?

Check [this page](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html), and look for entry smtpd_*_restriction (e.g smtpd_client_restriction, smtpd_helo_restriction and so on). There are many check on postfix for example but as I said above, by default only two checks enabled.

> what kind of filters / milters are useful to prevent accepting spoofed mails?

There are some milter/third apps to provide assists postfix battle spoofed email by applying four techniques I said above. For example [tumgreyspf](http://www.tummy.com/software/tumgreyspf/), [opendkim](http://www.opendkim.org/), [opendmarc](http://www.trusteddomain.org/opendmarc/) and many others.