# If I create a virtual email alias that forwards a lot of spam email, is my IP at risk of blacklisting or the originating IP address?

Tags: email, postfix, blacklist

A scenario of this would be something like a domain called `domain.com` has a mailserver set up that forwards all email sent to `info@domain.com` to `person@gmail.com`. If someone sends a lot of spam to `info@domain.com`, is my mailserver at `domain.com` at risk of being blacklisted?

Note: I do not intend to spam, I just want to know if my server would be at risk.

Comment: **YES**, there are people who blacklisted because forwarding spam. See these questions: [Postfix forwards to Gmail being rate limited even with unmodified headers](http://serverfault.com/q/658313/218590) and [How can I avoid being classified as spammer when I forward mail to a gmail account?](http://serverfault.com/q/665754/218590)

Comment: Both of those questions relate to rate limiting issues, which doesn't surprise me at all. My question is specifically about blacklisting. –  paranoid-android 13 mins ago

Comment: In *my opinion*, rate limiting was kind of temporary blacklisting. Anyway, my advice is same: **Don't forward spam**

Answer (score 1):

Blacklisting and Rate-limiting do work on IP-basis on most cases. Two criteria (of many others) for being blacklisted or - in general - get a bad reputation are:

- Amount of emails sent
- Probability that these emails are spam

  - Mail introspection (analysis of the body)
  - no SPF record for the domain used
  - no DKIM used by the mailserver

The latter two are very important for Gmail. If you don't use DKIM you get rate-limited quite fast. Whith DKIM in place, you can send much more mail before being limited.

For your setup, @masegaloeh already linked the relevant threads: [Postfix forwards to Gmail being rate limited even with unmodified headers](https://serverfault.com/q/658313/218590) and [How can I avoid being classified as spammer when I forward mail to a gmail account?](https://serverfault.com/q/665754/218590)