# Sane Spam Strategy

Tags: spam, spamassassin, procmail

Right now I'm using spamd to score spam and then procmail to put it in user's .Spam Maildir folder and then manually running sa-learn on .LearnAsSpam and .LearnAsHam and then also manually just deleting everything in those folders. Clearly there must be a better way and I just don't know what it is.

Is there a better spam tool chain that handles these details?

Comment: Did you read [Fighting Spam - What can I do as an: Email Administrator, Domain Owner, or User?](http://serverfault.com/q/419407/126632)

Comment: That's a great read. I will study it intently. But it doesn't really address the specific question which is wrt post processing of spam. But now I'm wondering if I can leverage some of these other techniques and actually not use Bayes at all. Although I would still need to device a method of deleting old spam.

Comment: After all the other stuff, I don't get enough spam incoming for SpamAssassin to do much of anything useful. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used the next approach:

MTA is the `exim` that pass the copy of message to the `spamassassin` from the DATA ACL. `SA` returns the score and do not perform any message modifications or routing. If calculated score is above the threshold, `exim` add some special header (X-Spam-Detected: YES) to the message.

Then message is routed for local delivery via `dovecot`'s `deliver`. `Dovecot` have `pidgeonhole` plugin installed that is the `sieve` engine implementation. When message satisfy some conditions (f.e. header "X-Spam-Detected" exists) `pidgeonhole` store the message in the inbox' subfolder:

```
if exists "X-Spam-Detected"
{
   fileinto "Junk";
   stop;
}
```

If message is detected wrong (false-positive or false-negative) user can move the message to the right place. `Dovecot` have another plugin called `antispam` that track message movements. When message is moved TO the "Spam" subfolder, automatically `sa-learn --spam` is launched for that message. When message is moved FROM the "Spam" subfolder, `sa-learn --ham` is launched.

Old messages can be removed automatically with `doveadm` utility:

```
doveadm expunge -A mailbox Junk  savedbefore 31d
```