# Forward then block emails received from a specific address

Tags: email, postfix, spam

On our server we receive malicious email from a specific sender.
Is it possible with postfix to:

1. Forward the emails received from this sender on a specific email (other domain name)
2. Block these emails on our domain mailboxes

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you want to get rid of spam.

There are many ways to achieve this :

- read [Fighting Spam - What can I do as an: Email Administrator, Domain Owner, or User?](https://serverfault.com/questions/419407/fighting-spam-what-can-i-do-as-an-email-administrator-domain-owner-or-user)
- You can use canonical maps in postfix (http://www.postfix.org/canonical.5.html)
- You can use firewall rules to ban the malicious ip (iptables of pf setup can detailed depending on your os)

Update : If you really want to receive the mail and take appropriate action about it, like forwarding, archiving or executing a shell script, the best tools for you are procmail or maybe mailfilter :

- http://www.zer0.org/procmail/quickref.html provides documentation on how to "Forward to other address",  "Feed to a shell command pipeline " or " Save to a folder ".
- mailfilter is my prefered tool for this type or problem, but it is necessary to have one configuration file per recipient

Comment: It's not really spam it is invasive email from some individuals. I still want to keep a record of these emails for a potential trial. So SPAM will not really answer my need: forward then delete/reject.