# Getting all internet domains a user owns

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, web

Is it possible to find out which other domains a user has registered? my company is atm recieving a lot of spam mail and the sender just buys a new domain and keeps spamming, so i wanted to know if i could write a automated script that would check for his domains, or atleast ones in a while look it up and block the domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to search domains from whois database based on owner name or email: the database is only meant for finding contact information for a domain.

> The WHOIS system provides information gathered from publicly available
>   information provided by the domain name owner to their individual
>   registrars. - [WHOIS.NET](https://www.whois.net/terms.aspx)

However, SPAM doesn't work that way. You should see the [Canonical Question about Fighting Spam.](https://serverfault.com/questions/419407/fighting-spam-what-can-i-do-as-an-email-administrator-domain-owner-or-user)

If you really have one spammer who buys domains in his own name and uses them for sending unsolicited commercial email, legally in his opinion, you could try to block his mail server based on IP address, instead.

Automating whoisdb based filtering would require:

1. Having an internal database of every domain used on incoming email in order to avoid excessive use of the whoisdb system. Otherwise, you would become the bad guy here.
2. Creating a custom filter that queries `whois example.com` every time a new domain name is present and `grep`s for the owner, then flagging the domain as one sending spam.

That would require much more effort than fighting the SPAM with the usual practices.

Comment: Thanks for giving advice my man, gonna try and look into it!

Answer (score 0):

You may try with `whois`, but most registrar allow "anonymous" domain registration (i.e. they don't show the real nic handle of the registrant), Thus chances are you won't get many usefull informations.

Automating this in this case would be even more difficult.

Comment: Yeah ive tried the "whois" and it gave me a name of the register, but is there a way to look up that name, and see what domains that guy owns?