# Spam rejecting configuration (Postfix)

Tags: email, postfix, spam

I want to configure Postfix to reject spam from the Internet. I found the following example [here](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html):

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject

smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_unknown_helo_hostname

smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, 
permit_sasl_authenticated,
reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, 
permit_sasl_authenticated,
reject_unauth_destination
reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
reject_rhsbl_reverse_client dbl.spamhaus.org,
reject_rhsbl_helo dbl.spamhaus.org,
reject_rhsbl_sender dbl.spamhaus.org

smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
```

But when I sent an e-mail to my domain from a Gmail account it got blocked. I then changed:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject
```

to:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_client_hostname
```

and now my mail server seems to work.

Is this example provided by postfix.org a best practise or should I strengthen/weaken it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fighting Spam - What can I do as an: Email Administrator, Domain Owner, or User?](https://serverfault.com/questions/419407/fighting-spam-what-can-i-do-as-an-email-administrator-domain-owner-or-user)

Answer (score 0):

That's

> Examples of simple restriction lists

It doesn't even try to be an example of a good overall configuration to prevent SPAM. You have removed the comment lines that clearly states what each of the examples are doing, e.g.

```
# Allow connections from trusted networks only.
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject
```

It does exactly that, thus it rejects all mail from the Internet.

Comment: Yes, I removed the comments for readability's sake. I changed that line you mentioned because I didn't want to reject mail from the Internet as that would make my mail server useless. I just want to reject as much spam as possible.

Comment: Rejecting spam isn't about amounts. You must take compromises to avoid false positives. You need to decide how aggressive you want to be. That's why there's no one-size-fits-all solutions. You'll also need to evolve as the spammers do.

Comment: I receive little spam so a good-enough solution will do.