# mail ends in google spam folder while SPF pass, DKIM pass, DMARC pass

Tags: email, spf, dkim, dmarc

I am trying to send basic mail to a gmail user test and the mail ends up in the spam folder. I don't really understand why. I used to send through ubuntu sendmail, spent a lot of time setting up postfix/dovecot but it still ends in spam. And the same with outlook/live !

I have looked at other posts but don't see how to solve it.

using Mxtoolbox, I don't see a problem  :
https://mxtoolbox.com/domain/gerant-immo.com/

headers seems ok too :

```
ID du message    
Date de création :  27 février 2018 à 16:54 (Temps d'envoi : 0 seconde)
De :    Pierre Mouilhade Message envoyé avec mail (GNU Mailutils 2.99.99)
À : test.gerantimmo@gmail.com
Objet : testing
SPF :   PASS avec IP 54.37.157.157 En savoir plus
DKIM :  'PASS' avec le domaine gerant-immo.com En savoir plus
DMARC : 'PASS' En savoir plus
```

```
Delivered-To: test.gerantimmo@gmail.com
Received: by 10.25.142.149 with SMTP id a21csp5148448lfl;
        Tue, 27 Feb 2018 07:54:26 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AH8x225LRChHqPMrsmVBeMzyZ80JcAFNz3ZGdA/iXknZaKJG85qi/B5PgdSHEzHjT1X/51LQc1bQ
X-Received: by 10.223.182.156 with SMTP id j28mr12863054wre.66.1519746866884;
        Tue, 27 Feb 2018 07:54:26 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1519746866; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=uyqDpNd/HSwglqKIzQ34pCAv38Ns0M43dzzFuLhwBz3ImRSGZdxXEH6RaDe9TDKW5L
         /e1K2Ih51KLjH43z2Dker5tmOzSlqSNIFnnFens3b8STr/1r0dnrjKhb0fgmbYYq8Zl3
         TJDa/CcwcBEp/kgfqP52fb/TxX2we1dEOEQLckBxvg4ihDg8gJ4ixf55Byi/QqKtnOrB
         NXrqCY0axq6qlcBQ1vDDbdKgrSTdpWctiMlcJN+IAWGOX8wBYxcw2r9oPlWq5p60h0T3
         vB9o2Fe1INVCZ7GvKPaUcQvhBs6mqH4HLeo7Zg+F9KE+K6ls+i8vyhamUCiw+/mgzZX3
         +B5g==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=from:date:message-id:subject:to:dkim-signature
         :arc-authentication-results;
        bh=nypZpg5l+81aPhtySK35KJDOOjKxnkP7R1HCZXGW3hM=;
        b=I2vwwSB4v0pK6Daa9NsWW7fC222N0hes9UVPHygu1GqtAjIlSaxUqzET158CsuKJQE
         gmKbRA1cQFYXpb6Kq0RhupMNzuaERiiEPWOWNwjh1SsSltCPkZGlotr6VwZjN9C9xN/k
         3O5bxBDZ+CiTVKutAU9RvDji50nWle1kSrb1D7+r/s5OJtJ6tlpAWtWCU9TZvui98sHB
         +o5gaUiCDzPszL9yOJ8tlm6EAlypTmqkAwN15RTk/A4qKO85DYgbQsW/N5j2GAsCPb6E
         yhBO+9tnEQL276GH+maPmAoFr+L3h6eUCflWQTYDVCXt1MuCZXj+jGeVfOKfJRiBNTsy
         OkHg==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@gerant-immo.com header.s=mail header.b=je4Cox0q;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of pierrem@gerant-immo.com designates 54.37.157.157 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=pierrem@gerant-immo.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=gerant-immo.com
Return-Path: 
Received: from gerant-immo.com (gerant-immo.com. [54.37.157.157])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id m2si877353wmh.123.2018.02.27.07.54.26
        for 
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Tue, 27 Feb 2018 07:54:26 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of pierrem@gerant-immo.com designates 54.37.157.157 as permitted sender) client-ip=54.37.157.157;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@gerant-immo.com header.s=mail header.b=je4Cox0q;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of pierrem@gerant-immo.com designates 54.37.157.157 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=pierrem@gerant-immo.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=gerant-immo.com
Received: by gerant-immo.com (Postfix, from userid 1002) id 7FCE4839C6; Tue, 27 Feb 2018 16:54:26 +0100 (CET)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=gerant-immo.com; s=mail; t=1519746866; bh=nypZpg5l+81aPhtySK35KJDOOjKxnkP7R1HCZXGW3hM=; h=To:Subject:Date:From; b=je4Cox0qlmTJAP6tatdYK8WyrvLALo3kjnjADH+zXsFy+Wp2ZS5yaj4/srqWe6dFT
     JChGxIJ7SUR6ytEJiadKwhkw35/FOimVj1lNSLKa/cP8ljpI7dn9l6WDDx2vdL/kqj
     1XSvi31gk2Cmi9nYCx+EYbxSHembKIQ/K0pRjfes=
To:
```

Comment: Google tells you why they marked the message as spam. What did they tell you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fighting Spam - What can I do as an: Email Administrator, Domain Owner, or User?](https://serverfault.com/questions/419407/fighting-spam-what-can-i-do-as-an-email-administrator-domain-owner-or-user)

Comment: hi all thank you for your response everybody. So all mails are going to spam and I never send bulk mails...

Comment: With regards to google, it's in french so I would translate it in "google spots that mail is similar to other mails". This is happening wheter it is mail sends by website or direct mails sends with customized mail like hey there long time no see how are you doing blahblahblah.