# SMTP Server All Records OK But All Email Sent in Spam

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, vps, spam

i bought a VPS with dedicated IP address and running windows Server 2012.
I installed an SMTP server and DNS server, created all needed records: SPF, DMARC, DKIM, PTR, MX, and A.
These results test all parts of my mail server:

#### SMTP TEST RESULT

[image: SMTP TEST RESULT]

#### SPF TEST RESULT

[image: SPF TEST RESULT]

#### MX RECORD RESULT

[image: MX RECORD RESULT]

And this is the raw email header:

```
X-Apparently-To: adel_hossienpour@yahoo.com; Mon, 01 Oct 2018 08:35:21 +0000
Return-Path: <HarswareAdel@mail.onlinegnet.ir>
X-YahooFilteredBulk: 185.116.162.231
Received-SPF: none (domain of mail.onlinegnet.ir does not designate permitted sender hosts)
X-YMailISG: vRDNEfkWLDszd_XzQp.1d0lW0uBnoKLWnjLLAwkx_We4O_cl
 .CdRPFOuPunHKx_jIXZwOtDEb8HwmO7cNc43fJMr.Q3fNbbvz8szdSkg4tla
 xPFrcTVxhGmhm4_pHcQIvJyidAae5K07RoUuXWkbKgvulOn7zmaYTKYCUOes
 GPcGHk1216PWm1kX_yMt6TxlUugTp15b5mz2U1uWiDK7m6VigIl6v.2Fq7Ei
 CGLQaH7o01IYQm1FL7nZKXDUwyFpHfJZuezeIsZtq2HY.nLMxpDe9NmeeibH
 5dIvnAxeOZD51lRee1XifG_NmYPa.K1sXzGmgIb97pf5UAagVJmpNDapjJZA
 C36Y5uhWlqCthuAeQTIrfXA.kS8xQDbMVdubB9XtCJmNmdfPMNYAqpNZiDsA
 WEjxJ7jFW7NFa6tm8teMUimlI15qrVCnqf7ipBJXn5Jfizg3wVw4qulXtxm4
 AG.jgHXfJtXu2bH4j5vodL7VwLiJPn5cGpK0uifID5erZ2arVWA01O90Nap8
 rzipXXZFrjGREAuAgoUA3x_VlGAy_ExRa1VhczykqWI_bsrCVNyrqD_5Ydeb
 ikhC_z0_xk6OLK7xXOY4bxS3d5rZCCkD.XYMeLJM38Wq4Ewnq8uEnmqCMxHF
 6o7EYu9UVE_BMzmVFSucdk4Y_k1nd3imtTVum1nTBRAm7GrHX2kK3uIYDNOu
 FYOWc_O7kABpXRcceFEokCdxHtM4xPokA3xfStou5XleUTSEWyybNVqRZPQI
 4tNeRYQuw1uieNHkov8t4ygN8oes75t0nepVMNl5EaYVZox9FDSlFbwPYnIP
 mg0_nkI3nZJQy3T27ET53gYTDOH5JE.KNQ.27_XnmHzJID1WDWyj_6PUY2U8
X-Originating-IP: [185.116.162.231]
Authentication-Results: mta4387.mail.gq1.yahoo.com  from=mail.onlinegnet.ir; domainkeys=neutral (no sig);  from=mail.onlinegnet.ir; dkim=neutral (no sig)
Received: from 127.0.0.1  (EHLO mail.onlinegnet.ir) (185.116.162.231)
  by mta4387.mail.gq1.yahoo.com with SMTP; Mon, 01 Oct 2018 08:35:20 +0000
Received: from WIN-EJCFGSELCJO ([185.116.162.231]) by mail.onlinegnet.ir with Microsoft SMTPSVC(8.5.9600.16384);
     Mon, 1 Oct 2018 20:44:44 +0330
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: HarswareAdel@mail.onlinegnet.ir
To: adel_hossienpour@yahoo.com
Date: 1 Oct 2018 20:44:44 +0330
Subject: Adel Hosss PC Release
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Return-Path: HarswareAdel@mail.onlinegnet.ir
Message-ID: <WIN-EJCFGSELCJOk4ll00000009@mail.onlinegnet.ir>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 01 Oct 2018 17:14:44.0586 (UTC) FILETIME=[3F8944A0:01D459AA]
Content-Length: 26
```

The body of the email is "Hi Adell OK".

Both Gmail And Yahoo send all emails from this server directly to the spam folder.

Comment: another Mail Raw Header :X-Apparently-To: adel_hossienpour@yahoo.com; Mon, 01 Oct 2018 08:34:01 +0000
Return-Path: <HarswareAdel@onlinegnet.ir>
X-YahooFilteredBulk: 185.116.162.231
Received-SPF: pass (domain of onlinegnet.ir designates 185.116.162.231 as permitted sender) difference is spf permitted ok

Comment: Please edit further information into your question (and use the formatting tools). It's not really readable in the comments.

Comment: When did you set your SPF records? It can take up to 48 hours for DNS records to propagate to other DNS servers. I'm not getting any spf records for your domain either, and the yahoo header clearly indicate that that's the problem.

Comment: Also, please see [this question and it's answers](https://serverfault.com/q/419407/126699), it contains a lot of information that you can use.

Comment: 72H AGO PLEASE TEST WITH MXTOOLBOX

Comment: You enevelope sender is HarswareAdel@mail.onlinegnet.ir but that address doesn't accept email: rcpt to: <HarswareAdel@mail.onlinegnet.ir> 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for HarswareAdel@mail.onlinegnet.ir

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to create a gmail account for testing purposes. Gmail shows you an explanation why e-mails land in the spam folder, see http://netgainstechnologies.blogspot.com/2017/03/googles-gmail-service-now-gives-you.html

One reason I see right off the bat is that **your SMTP server doesn't support TLS** which can already be a no-go for Google. I've never had issues with Gmail from any domain I administrated but then again, I never used non-SSL(obsolete)/non-TLS connections. Google is pretty picky about encryption these days which I think is a good thing.

Also the domain points to a non-https website, another minus for Google. Since free CAs like LetsEncrypt exists, there is literally no more excuse for not encrypting your traffic with TLS and Google is effectively enforcing encryption nowadays (e.g. by penalizing non-https sites in search results).

Another problem could be that the dedicated IP you have been assigned was previously owned by someone sending spam, thus destroying the reputation of the IP.

Also Google and Yahoo apply many more algorithm-based rules to determine if an e-mail is spam, such as number of links, where those links point to etc., see https://fulcrumtech.net/resources/avoiding-gmail-spam-filter/

TL;DR: Look up what Google tells you about why your e-mails are sent to spam (by using a gmail account) and deploy TLS for your webserver as well as your e-mail server.