# Sending large amount of emails with PHPmailer and SMPT guaranteeing the emails are delivered and preventing getting blacklisted

Tags: php, smtp, email-server, blacklist-prevention, bulk-action

I have been using Phpmailer + SMPT + G-suite to send 2,000 emails per day, to the registered users of our website and this worked well for a while.

Now that we have more registered users, this method is not working well for us, since G-suite has a limit of 2,000 emails per day and also their suggestion (G-suite) is to send 100 emails as maximum per lot, so that the system won't collapse. I followed their instrucctions and even like that, there is an average of 30% of emails that don't get delivered succesfully (eventhought the email recipients were valid).

We would really like to send all emails at once, which would be an average of 10,000 emails per day (only to our register users which have been receiving emails from us in the past).

We aware that many companies, maybe the majority of them, externalize this service of massive email sending to third companies. However, we would really want to evaluate how We can do this thing for ourselves, and keep using PHPmailer and SMPT.

¿What things should we learn to implement this properly?

¿The resources we would need to implement this are relatively high?

¿Is it advisable do it for ourselves?

*** As far as we learnt, there is nothing inherently incorrect with using PHPmailer for massive email sending... is this accurate?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Best regards,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fighting Spam - What can I do as an: Email Administrator, Domain Owner, or User?](https://serverfault.com/questions/419407/fighting-spam-what-can-i-do-as-an-email-administrator-domain-owner-or-user)

Comment: It´s a start for sure, thank you.

Comment: If G-Suite has such limitations, don't use G-Suite for sending these emails. Send them directly from your SMTP server.